# Displaying an embedded image on PyQt?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, pyqt

Let's say I have the base-64 code of an image in my script like so:

```
EmbeddedCode = """INSERTCODEHERE.....
.....EXAMPLEEXAMPLE"""
```

If I could decode it like this:

```
EmbeddedCode.decode('base64')
```

Then how can I display it in a PyQt4 gui like this?:

```
pic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
pic.setGeometry(0, 0, 512, 512)
pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(IMAGE PATH GOES HERE))
```

Preferably without having to use `open('image.jpg','w')`, if it's not to much to ask.

Note: I am using embedded images because I'd really rather not have a 'resources' folder. the less crap I have to deal with, the better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the *loadFromData* method of QPixmap:

```
from PyQt4 import Qt,QtGui,QtCore
import base64

# "b64_data" is a variable containing your base64 encoded jpeg

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = QtGui.QWidget()
pic = QtGui.QLabel(w)
pm = QtGui.QPixmap()
pm.loadFromData(base64.b64decode(b64_data))
pic.setPixmap(pm)

w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there a method similar to loadFromData that works with embedded sounds, and PyQt's QSound module?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea! Good luck